# Yasnippet: How to automatically advance to next field after `yas-choose-value`

Tags: yasnippet

Yasnippet has a function called `yas-choose-value` which is used like this:

```
<div align="${2:$$(yas-choose-value '("right" "center" "left"))}">
  $0
</div>
```

How can I automatically exit the snippet and move to `$0` after pressing the return key when making the selection from the choices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example in your question, you don't need a to make field, using a [backquoted expression](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#orgcde188c) should suffice:

```
<div align="`(yas-choose-value '("right" "center" "left"))`">
  $0
</div>
```

This doesn't cover the case where you might want to interact normally with some other fields first though.  For that, the new `yas-auto-next` macro [introduced just recently](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/937) can be used, borrowing the example from the docs:

```
<div align="${2:$$(yas-auto-next
                    (yas-choose-value
                      '("right" "center" "left")))}">
  $0
</div>
```

Which does the same as above, but will participate with any other fields you add in the normal order.

Comment: Whenever you have some free time, it would be helpful if your answer could reference issue 937 that implements this new feature.

Comment: @lawlist, oh right, I had forgotten about this when I pushed that. Edited.